# How can I know if a empty block is passed in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I wish `uriHandler.openUri(annotation.item)` can be fired when I don't pass a `block` paramater to  `AnnotatedURLText`, and `block()` can be fired when I pass one to it.

But I find `uriHandler.openUri(annotation.item)` isn't fired when I run Call A, B or C, how can I fire it?

**Code 1**

```
@Composable
fun AnnotatedURLText(
    ...   
    block: ()->Unit = {}
) {

   val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current
   ...

    ClickableText(
        ...
        onClick = { offset ->          
            annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(tag = "URL", start = offset, end = offset)
                .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->
                    if (block=={}) {
                        uriHandler.openUri(annotation.item)  //It can't be fired
                    }else{
                        block()
                    }
                }
        }
    )
}
```

**Call A**

```
AnnotatedURLText(...)
{
   todo()
}
```

**Call B**

```
AnnotatedURLText(...)
```

**Call C**

```
AnnotatedURLText(...)
{ 
}
```

**Added Content**

To Fogmeister: Thanks!

I write Code 2 based your ideas, but I get the following error.

*@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function*

**Code 2**

```
@Composable
fun AnnotatedURLText(
    ...   
    block: (String) -> Unit = {
        LocalUriHandler.current.openUri(it)  //It cause error
    }
) {
   ...

    ClickableText(
        ...
        onClick = { offset ->          
            annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(tag = "URL", start = offset, end = offset)
                .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->  
                    block(annotation.item)
                }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I do not know jolting enough to provide an actual answer for you but I would do this by changing the `block` signature to be the same as the `openUrl` function from the urinhandler and pass in the uru handler as the default block. Then you don’t have to worry about this. If the user does not pass in a block it will run the handler. If they do pass in a block it will run their block.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you please my added content in the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can inspect the contents of the function you pass in like that. Instead of making the default value for that parameter `{}`, why not make it *null* instead?

```
fun AnnotatedURLText(
    ...   
    block: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    ...

    .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->
        // run block if it's not null, otherwise open the URI
        block?.invoke() ?: uriHandler.openUri(annotation.item)
    }
```

`block.invoke()` is the same as `block()`, but this way you can do the null-checking.

Don't think there's any way to stop people passing a `block` function that "does the wrong thing" though!

---

If your `block` function is meant to do something with that `annotation.item` (so its type is really `(String) -> Unit`) then you could possibly just use a reference to `uriHandler.openUri` as the default value:

```
fun AnnotatedURLText(
    ...   
    block: (String) -> Unit = LocalUriHandler.current::openUri
) {
    ...

    .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->
        // run block, whether it's the default or a user-provided function
        block(annotation.item)
    }
```

So basically instead of making a local `uriHandler` variable that points to whatever `LocalUriHandler.current` is, and then calling a function on that, we can just grab a direct reference to that function on that object, and use that as the default value for your function parameter. I'm assuming things about how your app is written but it should work!

Comment: Thanks!  but`block: (String) -> Unit = LocalUriHandler.current::openUri`  will cause the error `Function References of @Composable functions are not currently supported`.

Comment: @HelloCW ah ok, sorry! Never used Compose so I haven't had to deal with that. I'd just go with the default null then in that case - it doesn't really matter, I just think it's neater having the default function defined in the constructor instead of in the code logic since Kotlin gives you the option!

Comment: To mitigate the error you can declare it as `block: @Composable (String) -> Unit`